# Is this an appropriate Huffman code?

Tags: digital-communications, coding

The problem is question 6.25 from Proakis, Communication Systems Engineering (2001)

> Design a ternary Huffman code, using 0, 1, 2 as letters, for a source with output
> alphabet probabilities given by {0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.17, 0.18, 0.22, 0.13}. What is
> the resulting average code word length? Compare the average code word length with the entropy of the source. (In what base would you compute the logarithms
> in the expression for the entropy for a meaningful comparison?)

However, rather than designing a ternary Huffman code I wanted to design a binary one (for practice) so here is my attempt at it (I followed the approach taught [here](https://youtu.be/GW4QJuuNtGc?t=2865) by Prof. Ivica Kostanic):

1. First label and then sort all the probabilities:

[image: sort]

2. Now use the sorted probabilities to generate the Huffman code as follows:

[image: Huffman]

3. Then trace the path for each symbol to get the codeword:

[image: codes]

The reason why I think this is incorrect is because, if I understand correctly, with Huffman coding we should be sending an equal number of $1$'s and $0$'s but I have a total of 21 bits and 9 of them are $1$'s whilst the rest are $0$'s. Similarly, if I flip the position of $1$'s and $0$'s in my arbitrary assignment (in step 2) I would get the opposite result.

Albeit the most probable symbols do have the shorted code words but the rest does not add up. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think that your assumption regarding equality is not correct. assume that you have two letters a,b with probabilities P(a)=0.9, P(b)=0.1. Are you expecting to get an equal number of ones and zeros, in case you code a as 1 and b as 0?

Comment: @GideonGenadiKogan I see. So how can I check if a Huffman code is good enough or not? Should I just compute its average length and compare it to the entropy?

Comment: what do you define as good enough?

Comment: @GideonGenadiKogan On the original note, I thought Huffman coding equalizes the probabilities across all of the symbols. Secondly, I guess if the average length satisfies this bound then perhaps it is good enough:
$$H(x) \leq \bar{L}(x) \leq H(x) +1$$

Comment: Well if your definition of good is the distance between the entropy and the mean bit length, why not compute it directly? The approaching is asymptotic. For specific cases, you might find a better alternative to Huffman code